# I get an error when inheriting from a template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am trying to work on a homework project that requires me to have a template stack class created, and I have to inherit that class into another one. The whole project works fine, including the stack class. However, once I include the file that inherits the stack class, the compiler can't find any of stack's function definitions and it says stack class template has already been defined.
Here is the Stack Class structure:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
     Stack();
     ~Stack();
    T data;
    Stack* link;
    Stack* top;

    void push(T);
    bool isEmpty();
    T peek();
    void pop();
    void display();
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
}
```

I won't include all of the functions here for readability.

This is the class which inherits both my stack and my file reader.

```
#pragma once
#include"infile.h"
#include"Node.h"

class Test: public infile, public Stack<char>
{

public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
    void output(char);
    void scan();
private:
    infile sequence;
    std::string s = "AACTAAT";
    int index;
    std::ofstream outfile;
    bool isString(int);
};

Test::Test()
{
    outfile.open("output.txt");//will just add to what is already in the file
}

Test::~Test()
{
    outfile.close();
}
void Test::scan() {

    Stack<char> mystack;
    //infile sequence;
    sequence.getfile();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < genome.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isString(i)) {
            std::cout << "Sequence found at " << i << " ";
        }
    }


}

bool Test::isString(int n) {

    if (s[0] == sequence.returnchar(n) && s[1] == sequence.returnchar(n + 1) && s[2] == sequence.returnchar(n + 2) && s[3] == sequence.returnchar(n + 3) && s[4] == sequence.returnchar(n + 4) && s[5] == sequence.returnchar(n + 5) && s[6] == sequence.returnchar(n + 6)) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

}
```

For context, the goal is to read from a file using one class, and use my created template stack to find a substring within the file. Like I wrote above, the project works fine until I include my Test class.

Edit: Previous errors are fixed by moving to a three file system, but now there is a new error.

```
template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    T data; // C2079 Stack<T>::data' uses undefined class 'T' 
    Stack* link;
    Stack* top;

    void push(T);
    bool isEmpty();
    T peek();
    void pop();
    void display();
};
```

Code works, I was inherting Stack instead of Stack

Comment: Please show your compilation command, as well as the exact error message you get.

Comment: Get all the `#include`'s out of your header files and put them in your .cpp file. I'll bet it will compile then.

Comment: @cigien I just hit local Windows Debugger in Visual Studio

Comment: @lakeweb but aren't these libraries needed in my classes to do the processes? I have my implementation in these header files as well.

Comment: If you put the necessary includes in front of the you headers in the cpp, they will be there. And the second set of code with `class Test...` looks like a header. Without the `inline` key word for the definitions, you would get a duplicate error. Not putting includes in headers can always be done, I can't think of an exception.

Comment: @lakeweb I have my class definition, then there are all of my method definitions inside of each header file.

Comment: And that's fine. But if you include that header from more than one cpp file, you will get errors. If you have only one cpp file, you will get away with it. Usually you would put definitions right in the class or in another cpp file. But about your problem.... From what you posted below, you must be including the class Stack header More than once.

Comment: @lakeweb OK, I changed all of them to be spread across two files with my libraries included in the headerfile, and only the header file included in the cpp. My previous errors are now gone. However, I have a new error, will edit the question so it can be read easitly

Comment: As for your last post, there must be something else going on as that error should not be there. At least with my compiler. Try it with `template <typename T>`

Answer (score -1):

First, it doesn't look like your Test class should inherit either `infile` or `Stack<char>` classes.

*Providing* Stack template is defined in Node.h file then I don't see a reason why the compiler (linker) couldn't find it. Maybe include the exact error message.

Comment: My exact error codes are C2244 for all of my Stack<T> methods, C2953 for Stack already defined, C2955 for Stack requires template argument list, and C2512 for Stack no appropriate default constructor available. Also, I HAVE to inherit these classes, it is part of the assignment.

Comment: I get the C2512 when I created Stack<char> mystack inside of my Test class

Comment: If you're 100% sure you must inherit the classes then the instance of Test **is** both a stack and an input file and so you shouldn't have them as a member (or local) variables.